# How to nest views in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a view that displays teasers of content type X (across all topics). Under each teaser, I would like to display links to instances of content type Y that share the topic (taxonomy) of that teaser. This seems like it should be relatively simple, but I'm having a hard time relating the filter criteria to the taxonomy of each line of the View's output rather than the taxonomy of the whole View page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Views Field View module to do the trick: https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view